# Анимация с задержкой

Tags: android, анимация

Использую повторяющуюся анимацию для 3-х кнопок и возникла такая проблема. Задал время задержки, чтобы анимация воспроизводилась последовательно для каждой из кнопок, но с каждым повторением время задержки автоматически увеличивается. Как избавиться от этого?

```
button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
animOne = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-20);
animOne.setDuration(300);

animOne.setStartOffset(6000);
animOne.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
animOne.setRepeatCount(-1);

button1.startAnimation(animOne);

button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
animTwo = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-20);
animTwo.setDuration(300);
animTwo.setRepeatCount(-1);

animTwo.setStartOffset(6600);
button2.startAnimation(animTwo);

button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnTime);
button3.setOnClickListener(this);
animThree = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-20);
animThree.setDuration(300);
animThree.setRepeatCount(-1);

animThree.setStartOffset(6300);
button3.startAnimation(animThree);
```

Comment: а может задержку стоит послать единожды?

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Если на глаз - там случайно не 300, 600, 900 получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StartOffset выставьте одинаковым, а запускайте анимацию в разное время:

```
         final long currAnimTime = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();         
         animOne.setStartTime(currAnimTime + 300);     
         animTwo.setStartTime(currAnimTime + 600);     
         animThree.setStartTime(currAnimTime + 900);
```

к кнопке прикручивайте методом setAnimation()

Comment: woesss, большое спасибо. Работает как надо!